# Add row through JS function with a cell in select option

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

I am trying to add rows to my bootstrap table with a click of a button which is working as expected. Each cell in new row contains textbox. Now I want cell with select boxes with options.

In order to add rows dynamically I am using following js funtion:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
    var actions = $("table td:last-child").html();
    // Append table with add row form on add new button click
    $(".add-new").click(function(){
        $(this).attr("disabled", "disabled");
        var index = $("table tbody tr:last-child").index();
        var row = '<tr>' +
            '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name"></td>' +
            '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="department" id="department"></td>' +
            '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="phone" id="phone"></td>' +
            '<td>' + actions + '</td>' +
        '</tr>';
        $("table").append(row);     
        $("table tbody tr").eq(index + 1).find(".add, .edit").toggle();
        $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
    });
    // Add row on add button click
    $(document).on("click", ".add", function(){
        var empty = false;
        var input = $(this).parents("tr").find('input[type="text"]');
        input.each(function(){
            if(!$(this).val()){
                $(this).addClass("error");
                empty = true;
            } else{
                $(this).removeClass("error");
            }
        });
        $(this).parents("tr").find(".error").first().focus();
        if(!empty){
            input.each(function(){
                $(this).parent("td").html($(this).val());
            });         
            $(this).parents("tr").find(".add, .edit").toggle();
            $(".add-new").removeAttr("disabled");
        }       
    });
    // Edit row on edit button click
    $(document).on("click", ".edit", function(){        
        $(this).parents("tr").find("td:not(:last-child)").each(function(){
            $(this).html('<input type="text" class="form-control" value="' + $(this).text() + '">');
        });     
        $(this).parents("tr").find(".add, .edit").toggle();
        $(".add-new").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    });
    // Delete row on delete button click
    $(document).on("click", ".delete", function(){
        $(this).parents("tr").remove();
        $(".add-new").removeAttr("disabled");
    });
});
```

Now I want to allow users option in the case of department:
so I replaced:

```
'<td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="department" id="department"></td>'
```

with the following:

```
'<td><select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select></td>'
```

But it is not working properly. Any suggestion to choose other form fields other than text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to close the string (single quotes), here sample code hope you got the point.

Maybe you can try handlebars or mustache so, it's make your code alot easier to read.

```
    var row = '<tr>';
        row += '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name"></td>';
        row += '<td>';
        row += '<select>';
        row += '<option value="volvo"> Volvo</option>';
        row += '<option value="saab">Saab</option>';
        row += '<option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>';
        row += '<option value="audi">Audi</option>';
        row += '</select>';
        row += '</td>';
        row += '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="phone" id="phone"></td>';
        row += '<td>' + actions + '</td>';
        row += '</tr>';
```